# How to insert/update `ARRAY` column in Postgres using Bookshelf/Knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have a table in my Postgres database which contains a column with datatype `ARRAY`. I am using Bookshelf to perform operations on the database. Now, I want to insert/update (append new data to previous data in an array) data in this column and I could not find a way to do this. Can anybody guide me on how I can achieve this? 
I think, one way of doing this could be using `raw()` function of Knex but I am not sure about how to use `raw()` function so please guide me on that too. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem [here](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/879#issuecomment-117402785). It seems BookshelfJS does not have a way to handle such operations so I had to use KnexJS. I implemented it something like this -

```
knex('users')                               //users table
        .where('id', id)
        .update({
            array_column_name: knex.raw('array_append(array_column_name, ?)', [data_to_append])
        })
        .then(function (user) {
            //Do something 
        });
```

Hope this helps other people in future.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the following table schema

```
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, data TEXT[] NOT NULL);
```

with example data

```
INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES (array[ 'def', 'ghi' ]);
```

which can be queried like

```
SELECT * FROM test ;
 id |   data    
----+-----------
  1 | {def,ghi}
```

You can use the [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html) to `array_prepend( 'abc', array )` and `array_append( array, 'xyz' )` like so

```
UPDATE test SET data = array_prepend( 'abc', data );
UPDATE test SET data = array_append( data, 'xyz' );
```

to get

```
SELECT * FROM test;
id  |       data        
----+-------------------
  1 | {abc,def,ghi,xyz}
```

You should be aware that the `data` column is not atomic and therefore this table schema does not adhere to first normal form (violation of 1NF). It will be more difficult to filter out values from the `data` column. You cannot use the `WHERE` clause easily, for example. Consider adapting the table schema to adhere to 1NF, better 3NF at least.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am aware of these `array functions` but I want to achieve this using BookshelfJS and KnexJS. Could you please guide me on that?

Answer (score -1):

```sql
UPDATE tableName 
SET ColumnName = array_prepend( 'Value', ColumnName)
WHERE ColumnName = 'Value'

UPDATE tblTest
SET TestColumnName = array_prepend( 'TestData', TestColumnName)
WHERE TestColumnId = '1'
```